# SSH Access denied to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS but only on Windows

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

I'm having an issue where I can't log into the Ubuntu 18.04 LTS server machine through Windows (I can connect on my laptop which runs Linux Mint and on my phone running Android 9).

Here's what happens when I try connect using `ssh discord@192.168.0.38`

```
C:\Users\Harry>ssh discord@192.168.0.38
discord@192.168.0.38's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
```

On my phone, I'm using JuiceSSH to log in, [See the screenshot here](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/502029505074954245/632133594713948172/Screenshot_20191011-193231_JuiceSSH.jpg)

And the exact same thing happens on my Linux machines.

Does anyone know why this is happening? And a possible solution? Once again, the problem only occurs on Windows machines

Comment: Does your password contain any characters, that would present different byte patterns on Windows and Linux?

Comment: The only special characters it has are '$#!^'

Comment: Try changing your PW to not contain `^` and retry.